# Swift 5 CoreData predicate using UUID

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, uuid

I have an entity for which I set some ID as UUID object.
And I have this function to check if it is already recorded in the persistent store.

I had found some forme of example that did not work as the example was using some '`NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #KeyPath(attribute), id)`' code that does not work in swift.

So I am trying to figure out how I go about this in swift. I would prefer not to store the UUID as a simple string since coreData lets us save UUID object.

I have this method but it is crashing on the NSPredicate line:

```
static func isKnownBikeID(_ bleID: UUID) -> Bool {
    let context = A18DataStore.shared.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Bike")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", [\Bike.bleID , bleID] as CVarArg)
    do{
        let bikes = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        return bikes.count > 0
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    return false
}
```

Edit: I get en exception with my curent method:

```
2021-07-16 11:55:28.390629-0400 A18 UAT[9260:4171027] -[Swift.__SwiftDeferredNSArray rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x282c22cc0
```

Comment: "does not work", could you clarify how it doesn't work?

Comment: You need to isolate the crashing line. it crashes because of ` [\Bike.bleID , bleID] as CVarArg)` Use `NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [\Bike.bleId , bleID])` instead?

Comment: You wrote it first `NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", \Bike.bleID, bleID)`, got a compiler error, didn't read it and clicked on "Fix", but important part was `Argument type 'UUID' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'`, no don't use `CVarArg`, use `Any` which is allowed with `argumentArray` parameter.

Comment: joakim: No it does not work I get an exception.

Comment: Why not simply `NSPredicate(format: "bleID == %@", bleID as CVarArg)`? And – unrelated – it's highly recommended to specify the real type in the request `NSFetchRequest<Bike>(entityName: "Bike")`

Comment: Larme: Thanks, got closer to the answer. Posting the working code below.

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Bike.bleID), bleID as NSUUID)` should work.

Comment: Martin R: the '#keyPath' is raising a build error.

Comment: @PascaleBeaulac: Strange, I have tested it in a small example, it works for me. Can you try the exact code that I posted below?

Comment: @MartingR : it does compile with the #KeyPath. now. after clearing the darn cache files for the 10th million time this week. That or possibly I had set it as #KeyPath(\Bike.bleID) but I don't remember started working on this yesterday, I do need to get used to using keyPath stuff.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- The `%K` format expects a key path string, this can be obtained using the `#keyPath` directive.
- The `%@` format expects an Objective-C object, here we can use the toll-free bridging between `UUID` and `NSUUID`.

That gives:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@",
                            #keyPath(Bike.bleID), bleID as NSUUID)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of help from @Larme

```
static func isKnownBikeID(_ bleID: UUID) -> Bool {
        let context = A18DataStore.shared.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Bike")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "bleID" , bleID as CVarArg)

        do{
            let bikes = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            return bikes.count > 0
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        return false
    }
```

This said @vadian is right.

The example I had was asking to do some manipulation on a key path, so I initially understood I HAD to use some .bleID thing to get it to work and yes just using the name of the field works.

Comment: I came accross same issue and it works with `CVarArg` or `NSUUID`. I can see on documentation what they are. Would it be any difference to use one over the other?