# Swift 5 NSFetchRequest predicate when trying to lookup a String UUID

Tags: swift, core-data, uuid, nspredicate

I have a string UUID coming into this method, to lookup an entity in CoreData that has UUID's saved as UUID type (Not String).

I keep getting "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on line for the predicate.

```
func loadUser(uuid: String) -> [ExistingUsers2] {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<ExistingUsers2> = ExistingUsers2.fetchRequest()
    let uuidQuery = NSUUID(uuidString: uuid)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(ExistingUsers2.uuid), uuidQuery! as CVarArg)
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    do {
        existingUsersArray = try context.fetch(request)
        print("Returned \(existingUsersArray.count)")
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
    return existingUsersArray
}
```

Any help? I haven't found anything here or Dr Google.  TKS

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68412528/1187415

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your predicate with this:

```
guard let uuidQuery = UUID(uuidString: uuid) else { return [] } // no valid UUID with this code
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(ExistingUsers2.uuid), uuidQuery as CVarArg)
```

Everything else should work.

***UPDATE***

This is the code that finally worked, thanks for your help @André Henrique da Silva

```
func loadUser(uuid: String) -> [ExistingUsers2] {
    let request : NSFetchRequest<ExistingUsers2> = ExistingUsers2.fetchRequest()
    let uuidQuery = NSUUID(uuidString: uuid)
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", uuidQuery! as CVarArg)
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    do {
        existingUsersArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching data from context \(error)")
    }
    return existingUsersArray
}
```

Comment: thanks Andre, unfortunately same error as koen, "Argument type 'UUID?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'" :(

Comment: I tried myself this code and it worked. Please make sure you're using guard let to make uuidQuery variable not an optional or do uuidQuery! as CVarg .

Comment: No errors, but also no result because the guard clause returns null

Comment: Hmmm ok, so maybe you should try and rollback to using NSUUID instead of UUID, I checked documentation and they are a bit different. So if guard let returns nil, it means it can't generate a valid UUID, can it generate a valid one using NSUUID? Also are you passing an uuid matching a value already in your database?

Comment: yes it did thanks
`let uuidQuery = NSUUID(uuidString: uuid)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your predicate: `NSPredicate(format: "cid = %@", "\(id)")`

where `cid` is the `UUID` in `CoreData` and `id` is the `UUID` you got from the string. Also do not use `NSUUID`.

Comment: thanks NoeOnJupiter, I had tried that previously, however it will not work either.
where uuid is String
`request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", "\(uuid)")`
build will run but query returns zero results. (yes I did check the query will succeed) 
when I leave the query as UUID type
`request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuid == %@", "\(uuidQuery)")`
I get "Thread 1: "Unexpected or improperly formatted UUID parameter with type NSTaggedPointerString, expected NSUUID or well-formed NSString""

Comment: is uuidQuery of type UUID or NSUUID? If it is NSUUID try with only UUID

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `uuidAttributeName` with your attribute name and `yourStringuuid` with the your string that you want to convert into UUID type.

```
var uuid = UUID(uuidString: yourStringuuid)

let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "ExistingUsers2")
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uuidAttributeName == %@",uuid)

let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

Comment: thanks koen, I did try that and I get the error that "Argument type 'UUID?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'" :(